# Problem about submodule of $Frac(A)$ generated by inverses of powers of $x$ being finitely generated

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a domain, $x \in A -\{0\}$ and $M$ be the $A$-submodule of $\text{Frac}(A)$ generated by the elements $\{1,x^{-1},x^{-2}, \dots,\}$. My question is: If $M$ is finitely generated, then it is true that $M=A$?

Obs: $A$ is an commutative ring with unity.

**My attempt:**

I tried interpret $A$ as a subset of $M$ by writing $a=\frac{a}{1}$ and tried to find an ideal $I$ of $A$ contained in the Jacobson radical of $A$ such that $M=IM+A$. The result then would follow by the application of the Nakayama lemma, but I don't know how to find such ideal $I$.

Comment: What if $x$ is a torsion unit, i.e. $x^n = 1$ for some $n$?

Comment: Let me reformulate the question then.

Comment: It's enough to show this after localizing at a maximal ideal containing $x$. Then take your ideal $I$ to be $(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $M$ is finitely generated. Then $\{1, x^{-1}, \dots, x^{-n}\}$ generates $M$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now
$$x^{-n-1} = a_0 + a_1 x^{-1} + \dots + a_n x^{-n}$$
for some $a_0, \dots, a_n \in A$. Multiplying through by $x^n$ yields
$$x^{-1} = a_0 x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} + \dots + a_n.$$
Thus, $x^{-1} \in A$, so $\{1, x^{-1}, \dots, x^{-n}\} \subseteq A$, so $M \subseteq A$. Also, since $1 \in M$, we have $A \subseteq M$. Thus, $A = M$. $\square$

Comment: You are the one who specified that $M$ is generated by a set which contains $1$ :)

Comment: To answer your edited comment: yes, it is possible. But if $M$ is generated by a set $S$, then $M$ is also generated by $S \cup \{1\}$. You can always add more elements to your generating set, and indeed every module has more than one generating set. So it can be misleading (to yourself!) to say things like "the generators of $M$" or "the finite generators of $M$". There is no such thing! There are many different subsets of $M$; some generate and some do not; some are finite and some are not.